# How to block checkboxes for checking when certain condition is met in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, count

I have a HTML form with a number of checkboxes that all have the same class = `"shared"`.

I figured out how I can count how many of these checkboxes are checked at a time using the following lines but would like to prevent additional checkboxes from being checked when the count has reached 3 so that never more than 3 checkboxes can be checked at a time.

How can I achieve this ?

**My jQuery (working part):**

```
$(document).on('click', '.shared', function() {
    var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
    if(countShared > 3) {
        alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `click` use `change` event (always try to use change event while dealing with checkboxes) and try below code :-

```
$(document).on('change', '.shared', function() {
    var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
    if(countShared > 3 && $(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ggkzyw7v/)

OR

```
$(document).on('change', '.shared', function() {
        var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
        if(countShared > 3) {          //<-------------here is the difference
            alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
            $(this).prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
```

[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ggkzyw7v/2/)

Comment: **`+1`** for `change` event :)

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot - will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: from user friendly point of view this is not the best way to go. you should indicate that more than 3 checkboxes are not possible/ wanted to be checked, one way would be to disable them as described in my answer. of course, this works aswell

Comment: @Alex..this is your personal opinion but in my opinion disabling checkboxes is not good as shown in your answer if you are disabling checkboxes then you should enable them also in else case.

Comment: as i said, yes you should add the functionality to re-enable them. still, it is more user friendly if a user can see that checkboxes are limited to 3 in the first place rather then clicking the fourth, getting an alert and having it unchecked again

Comment: @Alex..well ... in my opinion it is also a user friendly approach to alert the user with a appropriate alert message and make checkbox uncheck again if it exceeds count 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable them:

```
$(document).on('click', '.shared', function() {
    var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
    if(countShared > 3) {
        alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
        $('.shared').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

But you need to make sure when you uncheck a box that you re-enable the other checkboxes.

Comment: You should enabled them again if the user unchecked and number of checked items became less than 3.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$(this).prop('checked', false);` with your query

```
$(document).on('click', '.shared', function() {
    var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
    if(countShared > 3) {
        alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/zGEaa/1952/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.shared', function(e) {
    var countShared = $('.shared:checked').length;
    if(countShared > 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You have reached the maximum number of selectable checkboxes.");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nky51yxn/).